# Error:Failed to minify popper.js

Tags: reactjs

I am running the following command in my local cmd:

```
npm run-script build
```

The error I receive is below

```
Failed to minify the code from this file:

./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js:4:103
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I've found this answer useful:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23898

According to [popper.js docs](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js#dist-targets) `dist/popper.min.js` is an ES6 version (target=ESNext) while `create-react-app` build [require ES5 compatibility](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify)

To make build work you could use one of `umd` or `esm` targets according to your requirements:

`import 'popper.js/dist/esm/popper.min.js';`
or
`import 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js';`